# MYSQL error while executing SQL query stored in a column

Tags: mysql

I have two tables,

execution:

```
execution_id | order_id | execution_date
   1             1             2014-03-16
   2             1             2014-03-17
```

and queries:

```
query_name | code
  CNT_EXEC |  SELECT COUNT(execution_id) FROM `execution`
```

We have query defined in a column above. I am trying to execute this query using my code below;

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS query_execute //
CREATE PROCEDURE query_execute()

BEGIN
    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE s_query varchar(255);

    DECLARE c_queries CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT code FROM queries;/*since there are more than one queries in the actual query table*/
    
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
    
    OPEN c_queries;

    getquery: LOOP
        FETCH c_queries INTO s_query;
    
        IF finished = 1 THEN 
           LEAVE getquery;
        END IF;
    
        /*run the query*/
        SET @sql = s_query;
        PREPARE stmt FROM  @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    
    END LOOP;
    
END //

DELIMITER ;

 /*next I am trying to invoke the procedure and find the results*/

CREATE PROCEDURE queriesExecution()
BEGIN

SELECT query_name, query_execute() AS val
  FROM queries;

END
```

Going by the MySQL documentation, it seems I am using the correct procedure to create the procedure.But here is the error I am getting;

> ERROR 1064 (42000) in the pre-written template: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5`.

Comment: It looks like the queries table is actually "`execution`" table. please check again

Comment: you have to many problems with your approach i try to explain you can't use the stored procedure query_execute that way. you will get an error stored procedures are call with CALL query_execute and that you can't also use. For that approach you nedd a function but function can't use dynamic sql. so you adapt your pocedure that generates the wanted output. but even this approcach has it problems

Answer (score 0):

As i already wrote in my comment, your approach doesn't work .

But you can change it  a bit

**First:**

Change your queries, because you need a result

```
CREATE TABLE queries (
  `query_name` VARCHAR(8),
  `code` VARCHAR(355)
);

INSERT INTO queries
  (`query_name`, `code`)
VALUES
  ('CNT_EXEC', 'SELECT COUNT(execution_id) INTO @result  FROM `execution`');
```

As you can see the result is put into a user defined variable. so that ot can be used in the `INSERT INT myresult`

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS query_execute //
CREATE PROCEDURE query_execute()

BEGIN
    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE s_query varchar(255);

    DECLARE c_queries CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT code FROM queries;/*since there are more than one queries in the actual query table*/
    
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLe myresults(`query` varchar(255), result INT);
    OPEN c_queries;

    getquery: LOOP
        FETCH c_queries INTO s_query;
    
        IF finished = 1 THEN 
           LEAVE getquery;
        END IF;
    
        /*run the query*/
        SET @sql = s_query;
        PREPARE stmt FROM  @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        INSERT INTO myresults VALUES (s_query,@result);
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    
    END LOOP;
    SELECT * FROM myresults;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE myresults;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

when you now call `CALL query_execute();`

you get

```
query                                                        result
SELECT COUNT(execution_id) INTO @result  FROM `execution`    2
```

Of course as you add queries, you will get more rows.

this now assumes you get only INTEGER back in your queries, if not you must change the datatype.

This also only works, because your query returns only **1** result, if get more rows you can't use the user defined variables and you have to look for another approach.

Comment: Appreciate your reply. But couple of things, I am not being able to understand. First why do we need to re-create the table `queries`. Second, is it possible to get the output `result` of different data types. Do we need to create temp tables for each data type?Can you kindly help me to understand?

Comment: as i already explained `INTO @result` is necessary because of `VALUES (s_query,@result);`where it is inserted. to the second no only one type, so make a varchar and save the data in there. look play with it around a bit. and use more Selects.